# JQGRID autowidth of column header and column value based on size

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to JQGRID. I have a grid. I want the column width should be equal to the maximum value of the grid of the column heading whichever is bigger.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines about asking questions in the site's Help Center. SO is not a free codewriting service or tutorial site. You need to show your research, provide the code you've tried and explain HOW it does not work. As it stands, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not full clear what you mean and which version/fork of jqGrid you use. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is the fork which I develop. It contains the feature for automatic resizing of columns on double-click between the column headers or direct by loading. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Auto-adjustment-of-the-width-of-column) for additional information.

If I correctly understand your problem then you should add `cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true }` option to set `autoResizable: true` property in every column and to add `autoresizeOnLoad: true` option jqGrid to automatically resize all columns after loading the data.