# How to auto-resize all columns on doubleclick in actions column header in free jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid contains actions column defined as

```
{
    "hidden":false,
    "label":"",
     "name":"_actions",
     "width":72,
     "align":"left",
     "template":"actions",
     "fixed":false,
     "resizable":true,
     "formatoptions": {
        "editbutton": false,
        "delbutton": true,
        "delOptions": {    
            "url":"Delete"
        }
    }
}
```

Single column can be auto-resized using double click in column header. How can I auto-resize all columns if double-clicked in action column header.

Double click and double tap events in this area should captured and jqgrid `autoResizeAllColumns()` method should called as described in answer in [JQGRID autowidth of column header and column value based on size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599067/jqgrid-autowidth-of-column-header-and-column-value-based-on-size/)

Comment: Sorry, but what is your problem? You knows that one need to call `autoResizeAllColumns` method and you can easy see that the id of the header have `jqgh_list_` prefix and the column name. Thus you can bind an even using `$("#jqgh_list__actions").bind(...)`. Where you see any problem?

Comment: Height of `#jqgh_list__actions` is very small and it is invisible. It looks like using `$("#grid__actions").bind(` works

Comment: You can bind to the parent `<th>` (with id gridid + `__actions`) or to place some button inthe column header using `$("#jqgh_list__actions").append` or `setLabel` method. In any way I see no general problems, you need just implements your exact requirements. For example there are no double tap event and you have to save the time of the previous tab to detect double tap. All this have no direct relation to jqGrid and it's just a JavaCode which calls `autoResizeAllColumns` finally in some situations.

Comment: jquery doc contains `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.` so it looks like `on()` must used instead of bind()

Comment: I see no advantage of the usage `on` comparing with `bind`. I use only `bind` in the code of free jqGrid. Moreover, I use event binding *always* only on the elements, which already exist. Sorry, but all the discussion is far from the problems of jqGrid. It spends just the time. You know what you need to do and how to do. You can use the methods, which you more like.